# MySQL Error 1054 Unknown Column 'persons.PersonID' in on clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Here i am trying to run one query in MySQL editor and getting one problem

Here is my query

```
select *
FROM my_db.persons FULL JOIN 
my_db.employee
ON persons.PersonID=employee.PersonID;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `FULL JOIN`, so perhaps that is the problem.  In any case, I prefer shorter table aliases:

```
select *
FROM my_db.persons p LEFT JOIN 
     my_db.employee e
     ON p.PersonID = e.PersonID;
```

This, of course, assumes that the `PersonID` column exists in both tables.

Oh, I see why you got the error.  Perhaps this will explain:

```
select *
FROM my_db.persons full JOIN 
     my_db.employee e
     ON full.PersonID = e.PersonID;
```

That is, because MySQL doesn't support `FULL JOIN`, the `full` is treated as a table alias.

Answer (score 1):

Check if PersonID column exists on Persons table. Make sure the spellings are exactly the same as in the table structure. Also check the case. Some IDE are case sensitive.